# символы в сообщении

Tags: javascript, html

> На странице сообщение выводится символами,подскажите, пожалуйста, как исправить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> js фаил с сообщением

```
$("form").submit(function() { //Change
    var th = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "mail.php", //Change
        data: th.serialize()
    }).done(function() {
        alert("Ваш заказ отправлен! Нажмите кнопку ОК");
        setTimeout(function() {
            // Done Functions
            th.trigger("reset");
        }, 1000);
    });
    return false;
});
```

> mail.php

```
    function adopt($text) {
    return '=?UTF-8?B?'.base64_encode($text).'?=';
}

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . PHP_EOL .
"Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8" . PHP_EOL .
'From: '.adopt($project_name).' <'.$admin_email.'>' . PHP_EOL .
'Reply-To: '.$admin_email.'' . PHP_EOL;

mail($admin_email, adopt($form_subject), $message, $headers );
```

Comment: <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> в html прописан

Comment: Откуда сообщение берется? В источнике оно сохранено тоже в UTF-8 (кодировка файла, если это js скрипт)?

Comment: @Visman добавила

Comment: Не знаю почему, но ваш скрипт pochta.js браузером определяется как **Кирилица ISO**, хотя он у вас в **UTF-8** кодировке сохранен. В конфиг nginx директиву `charset utf-8;` попробуйте добавить.

Comment: @Visman честно не поняла куда добавить

Comment: https://nginx.ru/ru/docs/beginners_guide.html

Comment: а других вариантов нет?

Comment: Что-то не то в ответе написал :( **Вероятно нет**, так как FireFox 58 выводит текст сообщения читабельно. В каком браузере вы получаете свой результат, не знаю.

Comment: Я меняю текст пишу другои,даже на латинице alert("Ваш заказ отправлен! Нажмите кнопку ОК"); он выводит те же символы

Comment: в google chrome

Comment: Кеш в браузере очистите, чтобы изменения на сайте были у вас видны.

Comment: вот это помогло!спасибо)фаил script был с кодировкой 1251, видимо меняла на utf-8, а кеш забыла очистить.